# Does free() work on a reassigned pointer?

Tags: c, memory

Let's say I have the following code:

```
int *ptr = (int*) malloc(0), *ptr2;
ptr2 = (int*) malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
*(ptr2 + 1) = 3;
ptr = ptr2;
free(ptr)
```

Does calling free(ptr) work on the new memory block ptr is pointing to or on the null pointer?

Comment: Removed C++ tag, as there's only C here

Comment: FYI, the result of `malloc(0)` is not necessarily a null pointer. Per C 2018 7.22.3 1, it is implementation-defined to be a choice of either returning a null pointer or behaving like a `malloc` with some nonzero size except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Comment: You should not think of `malloc` and `free` as allocating or freeing *pointers*, that is, the objects of pointer type.  Objects of pointer type merely hold pointer values. `malloc` returns a pointer value, and what object or objects you store it in are irrelevant to its operation or to the operation of `free`. What object you use to get the value that you pass to `free` is irrelevant; only the pointer value passed is used.

Comment: @torstenvl: correcting the code in the question makes comments and answers inconsistent. Please avoid fixing the semantics of the posted code, even if it helps focus the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in your example `ptr` is set to `ptr2` which comes from `malloc`.

So, `free(ptr);` *is* valid (e.g. just as if we did `free(ptr2);`).

But, now, we've *lost* the *original* value of `ptr` so the block from the *first* `malloc` is now a memory leak. That is, no variable has the original value so it can't ever be freed.

To fix that, but retain your original code, we can do:

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(0), *ptr2;

ptr2 = (int *) malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
*(ptr2 + 1) = 3;

// to prevent a leak of the first malloc ...
int *ptr3 = ptr;

// without ptr3, this would "leak" the original value of ptr
ptr = ptr2;
free(ptr)

// free the first block ...
free(ptr3);
```

---

*Side note:* `malloc` returns `void *`, which works for *any* pointer type, so *no* need to cast the return value. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

So, in the code do (e.g.):

```
ptr2 = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

There is still some extra replication of code. The `sizeof(int)` would have to be changed if we ever changed the type of `ptr2`.

So, to "future proof" the code, many people prefer:

```
ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(*ptr2) * 4);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> You might also add a note about `malloc(0)` having implementation defined behavior. –
> chqrlie

Yes, `malloc(0)` has implementation defined behavior. Some possibilities:

1. Returns `NULL`. IMO, the best option
2. Treats the allocation internally as `malloc(1)`
3. Returns a special "zero length" allocation.

I'd *avoid* the use of `malloc(0)` for those reasons. It's "fragile" and of marginal utility.

I've [mostly] seen it used by novice programmers that plan to use `realloc` in a loop and believe that they can't call `realloc` on a `NULL` pointer.

However, `realloc` will accept a `NULL` pointer just fine.

For example, if we were going to read a file filled with integers into an array and we didn't know how many numbers we had in the file, we might do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 2)
        exit(3);

// NOTE: novices do this ...
#if 0
    int *ptr = malloc(0);
// NOTE: experienced programmers do this ...
#else
    int *ptr = NULL;
#endif

    // number of elements in the array
    size_t count = 0;

    // open the input file
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(4);
    }

    while (1) {
        // increase array size
        ptr = realloc(ptr,sizeof(*ptr) * (count + 1));

        // out of memory ...
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(5);
        }

        // decode one number from file
        if (fscanf(input,"%d",&ptr[count]) != 1)
            break;

        // advance the count
        ++count;
    }

    // close the input stream
    fclose(input);

    // trim array to actual size used
    ptr = realloc(ptr,sizeof(*ptr) * count);

    // print the array
    for (size_t idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        printf("%zu: %d\n",idx,ptr[idx]);

    // free the array
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: There *are* some rare occasions with special circumstances where doing `malloc(0)` *does* make sense. Usually, where the pointer has to be passed to some code that will discern a `NULL` vs. `malloc(0)` vs. regular allocation. But, they are an *advanced* usage and I wouldn't recommend them for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

free(ptr) will release the four "ints" ptr2 points to. Changing memory that is unallocated doesn't make it allocated.

I will warn you that there is a memory leak here. The memory originally pointed to by ptr will still be allocated but unreferenced.

Comment: *The memory originally pointed to by ptr will still be unallocated but unreferenced.* More precisely: The memory originally pointed to by `ptr`, if any, will still be allocated but unreachable.